# Regex and not condition

Tags: regex

I have below two regex expressions

- \d{13,16} - Number containing digits 0-9 of length 13 to 16
- 599999\d{10} - Number starting with 599999 followed by digits 0-9 and of length 16 digits

I want to say A and NOT B. How can I do that.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you show the source string and what you want to extract to better understand your requirement

Comment: Perhaps simply use a nested if statement.

Comment: Here is my string "DT1062-317  86457090            5999994347554632  4567891012345678". I want to replace the 16 digit number 4567891012345678 not starting with 599999 with xxxx .

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`^(?!599999\d{10})\d{13,16}$`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7YlIpB/1)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `(?!599999\d{10})`- negative lookahead to validate that the string does not start with `599999` followed by 10 digits
- `\d{13,16}` - matches 13 to 16 digits
- `$` - asserts the end of the string

**Edit:**

If these numbers are in the same line, you can use this instead [`\b(?!599999\d{10})\d{13,16}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/7YlIpB/2)

Comment: Beat me to it. I had just tested this same one in the console (minus the $).

Comment: i tried below string and got one match only "5123456789012345 5999991234567890 4567891011121314", it should be two

Comment: when i put them in a single line doesn't work. removed ^ and $ still incorrect

Comment: Yes because `^` and `$` tags are there in the regex. Use this instead [`\b(?!599999\d{10})\d{13,16}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/7YlIpB/2). I have updated the answer too

Comment: i modified string slightly to have characters before "abc5123456789012345 5999991234567890 4567891011121314xyz" this should result in two matches. Tried \b(?!599999\d{10}).*\d{13,16}\b and it matches whole string instead of just number.

Comment: removed the word boundry and worked. (?!599999\d{10})\d{13,16} but also matches ones starting with 599999

Comment: Sorry, was that a part of your initial requirements? You can't just keep on changing the requirements and make this thread longer and longer

Comment: No , I realized few other scenarios later on. Should I ask as a separate question.